# IE6 can't find Object element with getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get an object element from my webpage using getElementById (ultimately so I can replace it with a dynamically created object element) but it is returning `null` in IE6.

In the following code, the `byId()` function returns `null` in IE but an `[object HTMLObjectElement]` in Firefox 3 and the `lengthOfByTagName()` function returns `0` in IE but `1` in Firefox.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IE doesn't see Object element?</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function byId()
{
    var video = document.getElementById("VideoPlayer");
    alert(video);

}
function lengthOfByTagName()
{
    var length = document.getElementsByTagName("object").length;
    alert(length);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <object type="" id="VideoPlayer">
        <param name="allowScriptAcess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        VideoPlayer element
    </object>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:byId()">getElementById("VideoPlayer")</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:lengthOfByTagName()">getElementsByTagName("object").length</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the way IE treats <object> nodes vis-a-vis the DOM.

Since you're dynamically replacing anyway I recommend you instead create a <div> where you need it and change the innerHTML to be the HTML for the object you require.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I forget that backing up and approaching in a different way can be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I've just tested on IE 7 and seen the behavior as described

Internet Explorer doesn't expect free text in an `<object>` tag. Using Debugbar on you sample prooved that IE doesn't build the right DOM tree.

Use this code instead

```
<object type="" id="VideoPlayer">
    <param name="allowScriptAcess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
</object>
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Removing the free text does indeed fix the problem, but I thought that it was the correct way to provide fall-back content if the browser does not understand how to display the object element. For instance if a user does not have Flash installed.

Answer (score 0):

In IE6, it may not work. For refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396[magazine](http://note.taable.com)

Suggest using **jQuery** to handle most of the cases

```
jQuery

var video = $("#VideoPlayer");

alert(video);
```

Try this in your coding.